# Why is the Android resolveactivity of an intent returning null?

Tags: android, pdf

I am hitting a brick wall over something so basic. What I am trying to do is open up a PDF file with any PDF reader program that is installed like Adobe Reader. However, when I check for any installed applications registered as "application/pdf" it always returns null even when I have verified Adobe Reader is installed. Here is the code I am using:

```
String pdfFile = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.middleburychamberweb2014;
Intent pdfIntent = null, chooser=null;


pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdfFile), "application/pdf");

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(pdfIntent, 0);

if (pdfIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
   chooser = Intent.createChooser(pdfIntent,"Select Viewer for PDF file");

   startActivity(chooser);

} else {
  /* No PDF reader found on device. Provide user the option to
   * install the Adobe Reader found on Google Play.
   */
   Log.e("Directory","No PDF viewers!");

   noPDFReader(getString(R.string.doc1web));
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a resource URI to another app. It has no way of getting to the file. You will need to implement a ContentProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximately zero apps ever written honor the obscure `android:resource` scheme, which is why this is not working.

I agree with 323go -- use a `ContentProvider`, [such as `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). This requires zero lines of Java code to implement on the provider side, as you simply use `FileProvider`. It requires a manifest entry, one XML file of metadata, and one line when you call `startActivity()` to allow the PDF viewer access to the content. This is more future-proof than is writing to external storage, and it is significantly more securable.

FWIW, I have [a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrating serving a PDF to an external PDF viewer via a `FileProvider`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. However, I have downloaded your example from Github and installed it on a phone with a PDF reader and I receive the message "This document cannot be opened". Also, this may be related as well, I can view PDF files that I have downloaded to the phone by "tapping" the file name and the reader automatically executes and loads the file, but for some reason when I try to test for any readers from my app it always returns null. Here is the code I used for testing:  if (pdfIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

Comment: @maleman: What PDF reader are you using? Adobe Reader, QuickOffice, and RepliGo Reader have no problems opening `content` scheme `Uri` values.

Comment: I have Adobe Reader and Polaris Office. They seem to function fine when called directly. One interesting note, however, is there are no entries for PDF programs under my Settings->Default Applications.

Comment: @maleman: Settings > Default Applications is not part of standard Android, and so it is possible that your device manufacturer is interfering with `Intent` resolution.

Comment: I loaded the app on an older Acer tablet and to my surprise the chooser came up! Now I am getting a file not found error! I verified that the pdf file had been copied to the assets directory (not in a subfolder of assets). However, when I start the adb shell and navigate to /data/data/[my application]/files it is empty. The saga continues...

Comment: @maleman: "However, when I start the adb shell and navigate to /data/data/[my application]/files it is empty" -- you cannot access `/data` on production hardware.

Comment: I should have been clearer. The files are not showing in the emulator when I execute the ./adb shell and navigate to the app's files. Since I left my last comment, I was able to verify that the files are in fact in the apk package. I am not sure where to go from here except to continue to dig.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a content provider.

I did like this:
This very code opened up PDFs for me.

```
         fileName = "something.pdf"
         File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);  // these can be anywhere, really. but this app stuffed them here

         File file = new File(path, fileName); // get the path



         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

         String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
         String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

         intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);

         PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
         List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
         boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

         if (isIntentSafe) {
            startActivity(intent);
         }
         else {
            Log.d("SHOWFILE", "no intents available");
         }
```

Comment: This assumes that the PDF viewer has read access to external storage. That will slowly fade away, and I would not make that assumption even today. 323go's suggestion is correct -- a `ContentProvider`, such as Android's supplied `FileProvider`, is a better route.